# How to localize Autolayout Constraint added programmatically in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, localization, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

In my swift code I am using autolayout constraints. Some are added directly from storyboard and some are added programmatically on UIScrollView.

When the app runs in arabic version (RTL direction) the autolayout constraints added from storyboard they switch to RTL direction automatically without me doing any effort BUT the ones added programmatically on UIScrollView are not being flipped.

This is an example of my constraints being added on the UISCrollView:

```
        var previousView: UIView = self.productsScrollView

        for productObj in productsArray {

            let productViewObj: ProductView = ProductView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.productsScrollView.frame.size.width, self.productsScrollView.frame.size.height), productObj: productObj)

            productViewObj.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.productsScrollView.addSubview(productViewObj)


            // Left Constraint
            let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: productViewObj,
                attribute: .Left,
                relatedBy: .Equal,
                toItem: previousView,
                attribute: (previousView === self.productsScrollView) ? .Left : .Right,
                multiplier: 1.0,
                constant: 0.0);
            self.productsScrollView .addConstraint(leftConstraint)

            // Top Constraint
            let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: productViewObj,
                attribute: .Top,
                relatedBy: .Equal,
                toItem: self.productsScrollView,
                attribute: .Top,
                multiplier: 1.0,
                constant: 0.0);
            self.productsScrollView .addConstraint(topConstraint)


            previousView = productViewObj

... // width, height constraints



}

...// and left constraint (for the last item) is added here

    self.productsScrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Is there anything I am missing in my code? Or should I check for the language and flip the constraints manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `.Leading` instead of `.Left` and `.Trailing` instead of `.Right` for things which should change direction with the language direction. That's the whole purpose of `.Leading` and `.Trailing`.